# Instamojo payment gateway error

Tags: error-handling, payment, opencart2.x, instamojo

After I checkout choosing instamojo as my payment option, the following error shows up. I filled in the email field in the billing details and yet, it shows up. How do I fix this?

Notice: Undefined index: email in /home/thecoxiy/public_html/catalog/controller/payment/instamojo.php on line 42

[/This is the instamojo.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vWjc.png)

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPe2f.png)

I tried commenting the email line (line 42) in which case 'this field may not be blank'  still shows up except without the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the quick fix to this would be to push the email to session data and fetching it from there instead of order_info array, before you send it to instamojo.. I hope that should help.